# How do I programmatically get the size of UINavigationBar's title?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

From a UIViewController, I need to place a graphic on the left edge of UINavigationBar's title. In the diagram below, the asterisk shows that spot.

```
 ____________________________
|                            |
| <back|     *Title          |
|____________________________|
```

I thought a good way to calculate the x coordinate of that spot was this formula:

```
self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0 - titleWidth / 2.0
```

If I could extract the UIFont of UINavigationBar's titleTextAttributes, I would be able to get the CGSize of the title.

```
CGSize titleSize = [self.title 
    sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)[self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes      
    objectForKey:@"font"]];
```

To my dismay, the UIFont is nil.

Comment: btw it's certainly not the compiler who failed, it is either you or the compilation...

Answer (score 0):

How about looking through the `UINavigationBar`'s subviews until you find a `UITextField`, then checking its size?

Comment: this is not the problem, and using undocumented code will fail a day. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mis/not read the docs? UIFont is a proper Objective-C class to be used through pointers.

Use:

```
(UIFont *)[titleTextAttributes objectForKey:@"font"];
```

instead.

Comment: I have changed the casting to `UIFont*`, but this object is nil in viewDidAppear.

Comment: then titleTextAttributes doesn't have this entry, try NSLogging titleTextAttributes itself.

Comment: `{
    TextColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.4 1";
    TextShadowColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1";
    TextShadowOffset = "UIOffset: {0, 1}";
}` This doesn't appear to have any useful information for finding out the font of the title. I know the font is a boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0, but I am worried on different hardware (iPad vs iPhone) and OS (future version 6) it could change.

Comment: That means you can't get the font from the text attributes dict, from what documentarion have you got the @"font" key?

Comment: The UINavigationBar documentation lead me to this [constants page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893), which states there is a `NSString *const UITextAttributeFont` key for text attributes. The documentation seems to be faulty, because even when I replaced @"font" with UITextAttributeFont, I continued to get a nil font.

Comment: @JoJo apparently yes -- or we both miss something.